# Why does a process get blocked if a thread waits for I/O in many to one mapping

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

Why does a multi-threaded process using a user level thread library get blocked when one of its threads waits for an I/O? This makes sense, but when I think more, a question pops up. Can the user level thread library not schedule another thread?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Do you have a question about a specific programming language? A specific operating system? A specific library? Do you have an example of code that does not behave the way you expect it to behave?

Comment: Because the OS isn't aware of threading in this case. For the user-level library to schedule a different thread it has to run. And as far as the OS is concerned the process is blocked due to I/O request.

Comment: @jameslarge this question is very broad and not specific to any operating system or programming language.

Comment: @TonyTannous: sounds as nonsense. Of course OS **is** aware about process threading, and blocking entire process because of a thread waiting for I/O doesn't make sense actually. In windows, for example, there's an "overlapped I/O", which allows you not to block even a single thread during I/O.

Comment: @valdo Well, to be fair, IOCP GetQueuedCompletionStatus(), and other mechanisms for handling overlapped I/O, are blocking calls.  If there is no I/O complete, the calls block.  You can certainly set the timeout to 0, but that's just polling - a waste of CPU and memory-bandwidth.

Comment: @MartinJames: ok, it's blocking. But the OS blocks only this specific thread that called that specific function, and it's blocked only when it calls this function, not when the I/O was issued.

Answer (score 2):

OS can schedule only the processes(or jobs) , it in no way knows about the threads within a program and cannot schedule them as it wants.
when a part of the process ( here the thread which got blocked due to i/o) gets blocked for i/o operation, the os suspends the entire process , since the os deals only with the processes (not threads within the process).
As in the many to one model , there is only a single kernel , the process whose thread was blocked cant be executed until the blocked thread resumes.
whereas in a many to many or one to one model, each kernel runs its piece of code and is unaware of the threads blocked in the other kernels.

Comment: will the process gets blocked only when the thread blocks on I/O or does it block even when the thread blocks on mutex/semaphore.

Answer (score 1):

There's two types of thread. OS threads, and green threads (which is what I think you're talking about).

OS threads are scheduled by the operating system, and one will not block another (at least not on any OS you're likely to come across these days) unless you deliberately introduce something to synchronise them (e.g. Semaphores).

Green threads, where a process schedules different paths of execution for itself, will block unless the scheduler is clever enough provide (and therefore catch) all potentially blocking function calls and use them as a scheduling opportunity. This is also closely related to cooperative multitasking.

So the answer is yes, but only if written that way. Threads in Python famously were not written this way, read up on the GIL, and so would cause no end of problems. Python may have fixed this now.

Comment: will the process gets blocked only when the thread blocks on I/O or does it block even when the thread blocks on mutex/semaphore.

Comment: @Darshanb, the problem as was originally experienced in Python was that if a thread blocked on IO, that blocked the whole process and all its threads. IO inevitably involves the OS. For mutexes and semaphores, a green threads scheduler is likely providing "pretend" versions of those that don't map down to the OS. And so a green thread blocked on one of those won't be blocked in the OS (it's not got that far), and so the process as a whole stays running. However if a green thread had managed to open a real OS mutex, and waited on it, that would block the process.

Comment: @Darshanb Basically, if anything in the process gives the OS an excuse to block it (I/O, mutexes, etc) then the OS will do so. To the OS, a process that's managing it's own collection of green threads looks like a single thread of execution. So running such a process on a multi-core computer (like we all have today) does not give a speed increase.

Comment: @Darshanb As you can imagine, writing a green thread scheduler is not so very different to writing a whole OS + libraries of things resembling semaphores, mutexes, condition variables, etc. It used to be a little fashionable because it was a way of cutting out OS context switch times from thread scheduling, making everything a little faster. However, this was only the case on single core computers (so only one thread ran at a time regardless of what did the scheduling). Nowadays with multi-core computers it makes more sense to let the OS do the scheduling.

Comment: Consider a process having multiple threads. the user level threads will map to a single kernel thread(architecture dependent). The pthread_mutex lock is also a system call, so the OS will know that the thread will be blocked on a MUTEX. How is this different from being locked on IO?

Comment: @Darshanb, hello again :-) It's no different. Something else has to release the mutex, similar to something else has to unblock the I/O channel. In both cases the "something else" cannot be another green thread in the same process.

Comment: @Darshanb, for clarity, in OSes like Linux or Windows using the standard C libraries (or any other higher level language), when you call pthread_create() that will make a proper OS thread that will be scheduled by the OS. It's pthread_mutex_lock() will be taking an OS mutex. If you used an alternate library of routines that included a green threads scheduler, its version of pthread_create() wouldn't be making an OS thread, and its version of pthread_mutex_lock() wouldn't be interacting with an OS mutex. But you might not notice the difference when you run it (other than speed!).

Comment: The posix threads are not kernel level threads, they are user level threads. Please find the details. https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15492-f07/www/pthreads.html

Comment: Further if they are user level threads the OS should not know about them.

Comment: @Darshanb, ah, I think I see where the confusion is coming from! User level threads as created by pthread_create() in glibc are still scheduled by the OS, just as kernel threads are. The OP for this question was asking about what's commonly called "green threads", but in their question used the term "user level thread library". This is probably where the confusion has originated.